# OAuth flow only works on refresh, not when a link is clicked

Tags: reactjs, oauth, proxy, passport.js

I have my client side running on port 3000 and a node/express server running on port 5000. In order to kick the user into the OAuth flow, I made a NavLink element that would navigate you to localhost:5000/auth/google

Well, I setup the proxy below in order to allow the user to be directed to the google sign in page. The NavLink does link to the appropriate URL, however, it does not direct me to sign in. The page stays the same and it's not until I reload the page that it actually takes me to the Google sign in page. How do I have the link take me to sign in page without having to reload the page?

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy(["/api", "/auth/google"], { target: "http://localhost:5000" }));
};
```

Comment: I realize now that since nothing changed React-wise, none of the components re-rendered. I'm going to toggle the "login" button with a "logout" button once it's clicked and that should solve the issue. On re-render, the page should re-direct me to the oauth flow.

Comment: FIXED: I actually fixed it by replacing the NavLink tag with a hyperlink tag (<a><a/>), since the hyperlink tag refreshes the page after it's clicked.